# Selecting features and create new field with QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, query, select-by-attribute

For example, `Column A (1, Michigan Street, Michigan)`, `Column B (Michigan Street)` and `Column C (Yes, No)`.

I want to use Field Calculator to update `Column C` in a way that it return **NO** if `Column A` contains the same street name as `Column B`. However, it does not work. What I tried:

```
Case
when "Column A" LIKE '%"Column B"%' then 'No'
else 'Yes'
end
```

So I try to go longer route by selecting features in `Column A` if it has exact words in `Column B`

```
"Column A" LIKE '%Column B%'
```

but it doesn't work either. Any idea on what expression to use as I don't want to write every code differently according to `Column B`?

Comment: Asking about "Query Builder" is misleading, as it could mean you're asking about the SQL query/provider feature builder. You are asking about QGIS expression string builder/Field calculator.

Comment: Does the field `Column A` follow the pattern on `something, street, something`?

Comment: Yes. It does follow a pattern of house number, street name and district.

Answer (score 4):

Use this expression:

```
case 
    when regexp_match ("Column A", "Column B") > 0
    then 'No'
    else 'Yes'
end
```

The function [`regexp_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-match) looks if the string of `"Column B"` is contained inside `"Column A"`. It returns the position of the first character and 0 if the string is not found.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The proper syntax is :

```
Case
when "Column A" LIKE '%' || "Column B" || '%' then 'No'
else 'Yes'
end
```

(You need to concatenate the column content with the '%' using the pipe operator)

Of course you also could use the alternative expression provided by @Babel